# jsp?Action=someaction not working but jsp?action=someaction works

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my web application, I use jsp and servlets. To redirect to a page, I use the following URL Pattern with some action.

**This does not work.**

1.http://100.320.22.1423:1023/hello/SomePage.jsp?Action=Det&FunctionId=ID123

These work. As you can see, the only difference between 1 and 2 are 'Action' starts with capital and simple letters. I encountered these problems afrer updating my browers ( both Chrome and firefox )

2.http://100.320.22.1423:1023/hello/SomePage.jsp?action=Det&FunctionId=ID123
3.http://100.320.22.1423:10023/hello/SomePage.jsp?FunctionId=ID123&Action=Det

Any suggestion or reasons why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code are you using to access the `action` variable?

Comment: Query parameter names are case-sensitive. Any reason you would think they are not?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @ryansin I am taking the url from a database. Andreas, this works even when the url is like http://100.320.22.1423:1023/hello/SomePage.jsp?AnyStringAction=Det&FunctionId=ID123 I am lost here.

Comment: Show the Servlet code that processes the request. How do you expect us to help you when you don't show the code, and don't explain what "does not work" means? --- This is what ryansin was asking for, i.e, what *Servlet* code are you using the access the `action` query parameter on the server. ryansin wasn't asking where the URL originated, but about the server code used to *process* the request.

Comment: @Ran_Macavity We can't help you unless we can see what you've already tried

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to help me. The reason I cannot exactly show an error is that there is no error log. Broweser does not forward the request ( In chrome request goes to 'staled' state where request is not committed. ) Regarding not posting the code, yes I will keep that in mind in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think it's really important that you consider how you can help other people help you when writing your question. You have not included any details about the error, nor your code, which is why you've been down-voted so many times.

I suggest you read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can craft better questions in the future that may lead you to quicker, better answers.

Without the code or the error message it's really difficult to help you out. However, I suspect you're probably not considering the case-sensitivity of `action` (or `Action`).

`A` and `a` are not the same, so `Action` and `action` need to be accessed differently.

If you want to read `Action` in PHP for example, you would need to access the `$_GET` array with the index `Action`.

```
$action = $_GET["Action"];
```

Using `action` with a lower-case "a" will result in an error saying that the index is undefined.

Comment: Thanks ryansin, I will follo the suggestion.